# Visual Studio 2012: WebDev.WebServer40.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a very large MVC4 project.

Windows 7 64 bit, .NET Framework.4.5, Visual Studio 2012 Premium SP1

I work in a corporate environment and every night machines are updated. On 4/22 I left my machine on with VS running but not executing any code. On 4/23 in the morning I continued where I left off the night before. Machine response time seemed to be slow, so I rebooted. After the reboot I began getting this message when trying to debug:

**Popup in VS**: WebDev.WebServer40.exe has stopped working
**Web page**: This page can't be displayed

**Fiddler displayed this message**:

[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:51043

**The Windows Application log displays this error**:

Faulting application name: WebDev.WebServer40.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011ca7e
Faulting module name: **ole32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514**, time stamp: 0x4ce7b96f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000408a7
Faulting process id: 0x280
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf60dbe460d837
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
Report Id: 22f43805-cccf-11e3-866d-00270e269f58

**NOTE**: It looks like ole32.dll is implicated. Checking, I discovered that there is a known error in several versions, however, none of those versions exactly match **6.1.7601.17514** so I have been cautious about replacing it.

Working with networking engineers I determined that the issue is within VS. The app will run with Ctrl-F5 and WebDev.WebServer40.exe appears in the list of processes. Using F5 WebDev.WebServer40.exe appears briefly in the list of processes, then disappears as the error appears. Summoning the app from the browser works, too, however if I use F5 to try and debug WebDev.WebServer40.exe disappears from the list of processes.

**I have tried the following**:

- Repaired .NET Framework 4.5.1
- Cleared Visual Studio's temporary files
- Operated other apps to determine if the cause is in the app. All other apps on my machine fail in the same way
- Deleted browser cookies
- Added/subtracted localhost entries in the Hosts file
- Attempted to repair VS 2012 but that generates an error messages: (1) log files full and (2) some features were not installed

My associates and I are out of ideas and I am ready to completely uninstall VS2012 and reinstall, with all the time, effort and risk that entails unless someone else has a clearer idea of what might be happening and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Anthony and AlaN for your suggestions. It's important to check off possibilities with an error as vague as this one.

Microsoft support found the issue using the tttracing utility. A malware application had created a folder that contained: aecbbldsrvrc.dll.

...appdata\local\exction\aecbbldsrvrc.dll

That dll was getting added to the mix of dlls used for debugging. How that happens, I haven't a clue, yet. A Google search for aecbbldsrvrc.dll returns a lot of commentary.

And, btw, since I have disabled IPV6 and QOS on the network adapter I have noticed an improvement in network speed, thank you, Anthony!

Answer (score 2):

Even i got the same error message in my application of MVC4
"webdev.webserver40.exe has stopped working" and throwing an stack overflow exception.
then you need to go through the code,check for the spellings used for proporties. change the spellings and check.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run SFC /Scannow
2. Reset IE via Tools>internet oprions>advanced >reset
3. Remove Temp ASP.net files (see: [Can I safely delete the Temporary ASP.Net folder's contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617385/can-i-safely-delete-the-temporary-asp-net-folders-contents))

I had many "funny" issues worth my environment recently that wasn't even solved worth the win 8.1 update. The above tips solved my issues.

Update:  I have also found this today:

Fix .NET 4.5/ 4.5.1 issues with Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool 1.2
http://betanews.com/2014/04/29/fix-net-4-5-4-5-1-issues-with-microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-1-2/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed+-+bn+-+Betanews+Full+Content+Feed+-+BN

Comment: Hi Anthony. I tried your suggestions but without success. Yes, I've had some "hilarious" issues with my environment, too. Thanks.

Comment: I see in the webdev it refers to a IPV6 version of 127...1 ([::1).  Have you tried to disable IPV6 on your network adapter.  As a rule (as I learnt from Richard Vivian in the forums), I disable that AND QOS, which makes my network connection fly.

Comment: Also look at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/606216/webdev-webserver40-exe-spontaneously-closes-or-sometimes-crashes-when-attempting-to-debug-in-vs-2010 .  They refer to a workaround that may work.

Comment: A network engineer assures me that our corporation is not using IPV6 and that is strange given the Fiddler message. Do you know the link where Richard Vivian describes how to disable IPV6? Where do I disable QOS? Thanks.

Comment: Just do as follows to disable QOS, although it will not help your actual problem:  Network and Sharing Center >> Change Adapter Settings >> Right-Click Curent/Connected Adapter >> Properties >> Uncheck QoS Packet Scheduler.  Save, Save, etc.

Comment: I disabled IPV6 and QOS on the network adapter. I'll look for changes in network connection speed. Thanks.

Comment: If you copy and check your network speed under Task Manager, you should see a vast difference.

Comment: @ArnoldSmith Have you tried rolling back your machine's updates, i.e. using restore points - go back a few days to just before you had issues.  The restore point obviously does not do anything to your data.  Windows updates are from below, but seem to be necessary..

Comment: Thanks for the advice Anthony. I worked with Microsoft support and discovered the issue.

Comment: Great. Would you mind outlining the solution, as an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this article on the Microsoft forum.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ro-RO/b2e47862-a7be-45c9-9569-c6e045bcda7d/webdevwebserver40exe-stops-responding-when-launching-specific-aspnet-web-app?forum=vsdebug

Maybe this is a problem worthy of posting on the ASP .NET forum? http://forums.asp.net/

Comment: The post doesn't suggest an answer, and it summary should be in your answer - if this qualifies as an answer. Could you please check and edit?