# How to modify autogenerated code

Tags: c#, asp.net

First problem :

I am using some externall buisness libraries and they have strange namespace for example `System.Web.UI.Page`. Cant do nothing about that. Problem occurs in ASP.NET when libraries are loaded everything is fine but problem occurs when displaying pages :

> CS0433: The type 'System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState'
>   exists in both

So basically C# tries to compile page - but dont know which library to use for this type

I found solution with externall alliases but, then there is a problem in designer cause every time i modify page it will break naming( really hard to mantain ) - desginer will switch name from `"MyNewExternalAlliase"->"Global"`, or when adding new ellemnts they will show with global::. It will be really time consuming.

Question :

Can i modify this autogenerated code for ASP.NET pages/controls if i could somehow inject into process and do simple do string replace i could use double alliase and everything would work fine.  For clarification i mean this kind files :

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\f3552813\29b6906c\App_Web_XXXXX.aspx.65a2d1ee.p58-fzio.0.cs

Update 1.
You guys didnt understand problem, standard system library System.Web has class System.Web.UI.Page, library that i am loading during runtime has the same type( namespace and class ). And now when ASP.net compiles pages - *.aspx, *.ascx files are compiled - it cant tell which library should it use and i get error :

> CS0433: The type 'System.Web.UI.Page'
>   exists in both dlls

Comment: its better to avoid to even try to modify the auto-generated code !

Comment: quick googling found this trick:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757289/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come

does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Using temporary files and directories is not a good pattern. 
Solution is to modify the code - please put as example.