# Server Error in '/' Application.Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager' exists in both

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am working on an website application, for this i am using ASP.net  c#  and javascript. I am a newbie to asp.net. Everything was working fine till now, suddenly i struck up with the above server compiler error.

> "Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager' exists in both
>   'c:\Users\Radhika\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\c59f3bda\449eecb5\assembly\dl3\1a213be9\0bd50721_22d7cf01\BanquetNew.DLL'
>   and 'c:\Users\Radhika\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\vs\c59f3bda\449eecb5\assembly\dl3\dc575640\0037b478_7df8ce01\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL'"

I dont know what to do,  I have tried googling many sites for solving this error, but still i am getting this error.

for 4 days I am sittig with this error.

I tried to change even batch="false" in the web config file, but still also no use.

Here i am using ajax tool kit for calendar popup and also two calendars i am using here.

In my code, am using

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

     <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkit1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
      <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="Bookeddate"  runat="server" />
     <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" TargetControlID="functiondate"  runat="server"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does error CS0433 "Type 'X' already exists in both A.dll and B.dll " come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757289/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come)

Comment: Try to clean then build.. (Right click on project and click clean)

Comment: i tried to clean up but still same result

Comment: CLose visual studio and remove temporay files from your computer.Type %temp% in start menu search box and press enter than delete all files.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your ASP.NET temporary files. I keep a few batch files around for this. Here is the one for .NET 4, 32-bit:

```
@echo off
echo Stopping IIS...
iisreset /stop
echo Deleting ASP.NET 4.0 (32-bit) temporary files...
for /d %%d in ("c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*") do rd /q /s "%%d"
iisreset /start
pause
```

EDIT: looks like that was the one for .NET 2.0. Anyway you get the idea. Run as admin.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure it isn't the most obvious problem : 
I assume your solution has a project BanquetNew which is probably your website project.
Could you open your solution and search for a class ToolkitScriptManager
If you did create a ToolkitScriptManager class (and even used the same namespace as the official ToolkitScriptManager due to code copy pasting) then this error makes sense and you would either have to

- rename your custom ToolkitScriptManager class
- change it's namespace
- delete it and use the one from  the ajaxToolKit dll

Answer (score 0):

Let me add something to this issue, because I had the same compiler error CS0433.

I could temporarily fix it be running [Reg Edit's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012254/1016343), but it occurred again and again, in Visual Studio 2013, and even when I deployed the web site.

So I considered [what Kristof wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012389/1016343), and that brought me closer to the root case: In my case the reason was that 2 controls had the same class name

```html
<%@ Control ClassName="MyControl"  ... %>
```

because it was copy/pasted (the `CodeBehind="..."` and `Inherits="..."` properties were different, but the `ClassName` was the same for both controls).

After fixing this (i.e. giving unique ClassNames for the 2 controls) as follows:

```html
<%@ Control ClassName="MyControl1"  ... %>
<%@ Control ClassName="MyControl2"  ... %>
```

the error did not occur again.

**Lesson learned:** A temp fix is okay, but always search and look after the root cause!