# error CS0433 “Type '' already exists in both A.dll and B.dll ”

Tags: c#

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028526
 there are 6 solutions mentioned here. And i have tried all
Its a very repeated question but i m stuck on it. I have tried almost everything 
deleting temporary files, setting batch ="false" , cleaning solution.  the only way my solution worked was when i dont set  output path for build i.e. its building and putting it in parent folder of bin or at code level.(it's the worst and messy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does error CS0433 "Type 'X' already exists in both A.dll and B.dll " come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757289/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come)

Comment: I tried all the things mentioned there

Comment: Do you actually have two identically named types within the same namespace?

Comment: nope.  its coming for master file refernce.. and there is only one master file

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt come up with anyting great. But i created output folder in level of bin only and named it as 'DLL'  Its working