# Asp.Net error on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have asp.net c# code and its working fine in my local pc but as i deploy it on server it throws an error see in the attached picture and also stack trace

> message: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\832d6e0a\60adae5\App_Web_employee.aspx.cdcab7d2.ob4tk_w7.0.cs(152): error CS0433: The type 'Employee' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\832d6e0a\60adae5\assembly\dl3\b0d7055d\82782d6b_fcb2d001\App_Code.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\832d6e0a\60adae5\assembly\dl3\755f92ca\f0f0aa6c_fcb2d001\App_Web_rczryygi.DLL'
>
> StackTrace      :    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
>              at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>              at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>              at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>              at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>              at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>              at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>              at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>              at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>              at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>           Inner Exception :

On client browser shows

> Runtime Error

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757289/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off

Answer (score 1):

Clean you Temporary ASP.NET folder which can be find here `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\` then try again it shall do it