# The type 'Color' exists in both "corecompat.system.drawing and system.drawing.primitives

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

error message is 严重性    代码  说明  项目  文件  行   禁止显示状态
错误  CS0433  类型“Color”同时存在于“CoreCompat.System.Drawing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c0a7ed9c2333b592”和“System.Drawing.Primitives, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”中    End C:\Users\root\source\repos\End\End\Controllers\HomeController.cs    199 活动的

Comment: Please from now on tag the *correct* programming language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does error CS0433 "Type 'X' already exists in both A.dll and B.dll " come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757289/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is talking about namespace collisions, then: you just need to qualify which `Color` you are talking about. You can do this either by:

- removing any unnecessary `using` directives
- using a `using` alias directive to explicity tell it which `Color` should mean in that file, i.e.

  ```
  using Color = CoreCompat.System.Drawing.Color;
  ```
- fully qualifying the type when used, i.e. instead of `Color foo`, use `CoreCompat.System.Drawing.Color foo`.

---

If this is talking about the same *namespace qualified type* (i.e. both are in the same namespace), then: you're going to have to drop one of the assemblies, or use "extern alias". In the VS IDE you can set the "aliases" of each dll in the property window. The default is `global`. By setting specific aliases against each, you can import those aliases - for example, if you add "primitives" as an alias, you can add (at the top of your C# file):

```
extern alias primitives;
```

That *might* be enough by itself, but if not, you can use alias qualified names:

```
primitives::CoreCompat.System.Drawing.Color
```

(which is `CoreCompat.System.Drawing.Color` in the alias set described by `primitives`)

Comment: ok,i can do it ,i install corecompat.system.drawing v2 ,it can let me use everything.

Comment: Extern alias worked for me with two different System.Net.Http references, you're a lifesaver

Comment: I cannot specify full name bacause it is in the same namespace

Comment: @kemsikov then the second half of this answer applies, and you're going to have to use "extern alias"

Comment: I kinda cannot add /reference because I use linux and have no visual studio installed

Comment: @Kemsikov the same trick can be done with any setup. How are you currently building the code, and where are the packages coming from? For example, using "csc" with local dll files would require different guidance to if you are using "dotnet build" with nuget package references, which would require different guidance to using Xamarin studio, etc

Comment: Nevermind. I'll just switch to SkiaSharp.