# An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. - Error on DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

This error is so weird. I have seen questions based on this error but my case seems to be totally different from what ever I have seen in SO. Below is the error screenshot:

[image]

What I have done till now:

1. I cleared the ASP.Net temporary file
2. I went to the locations mentioned in the error but not sure where to make correction. One thing I am sure of is - the 'ProfileCommon' is having multiple inherits which is the problem.Any Help?

Comment: Review and follow the steps listed in the accepted answer of the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757289/where-does-error-cs0433-type-x-already-exists-in-both-a-dll-and-b-dll-come

Comment: @David I tried all these and still getting the same error