# Visual Scripting Error After Importing IronPython3.4.1

Tags: unity-game-engine, ironpython

[image: These are the errors I got]

I imported IronPython3.4.1 into my unity project and I have received these error does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried deleting and re importing IronPython but that didn't work and I do now know how to fix it. Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: do you use visual scripting?

Comment: @BugFinder no i dont

Comment: then remove it :P save all the greif

Comment: i have just deleted it

Comment: now it says theres an error in ironpyton3.4.1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two versions, try fixing this by removing both from the project and then reading the correct version. References - check for the files with similar names and remove them. then re-add the correct version.

Comment: i only have 1 version in my project, ive deleted it and it now just says that it couldnt find it so i made a new project and added an older version of ironpython and it still has said the same thing @Agent S

Comment: i guess then you can use Namespace Aliases, like `using CodeDomStatement = System.CodeDom.CodeStatement;` let me know if this works @Randomguy660

Comment: or you can check this [ Where does error CS0433 “Type 'X' already exists in both A.dll and B.dll ” come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1757289/12338102) @Randomguy660

In short:
This can sometimes happen when Visual Studio fails to correctly clear out cached state as part of rebuilding.  Try the following steps and see if it helps:

1. Delete all bin/obj directories for your solution using File Explorer
2. Close VisualStudio and restart PC (this seems odd and unnecessary, but have found it can help)
3. Reopen VisualStudio and do a full rebuild

Comment: im sorry but i dont know what a namespace alias is becasue im very new to unity and im trying to make a game for my girlfriend which is like a treasue hunt, and i need to execute a python file, so i juts got back into unity so im sorry and i also dont know how to delete bin/obj directories, or more like where to find them, many apologise for your troubles

Comment: @Randomguy660 That is very sweet, wishing you all the best. namespace alias is just an alternative name. You can delete bin/obj from the file explorer, like how you delete a file normally. Go to the project directory and search for the bin folder. Also, visual scripting can be ignored.

Comment: do i just delete all of the files that are type bin because when i search up bin it doesnt come up with a file

Comment: i deleted the obj folder and then deleted every obj file and bin file and it still didnt work and now the bin and obj files are gone

Comment: how would i make a namespace alias, i am unable to edit the scripts for ironpython because i cannot access them so i dont know how i would put them into a namespace

Comment: new issue now, i deleted all the visual scripting things and now its saying there is an error in ironpython3.4.1 how can i fix this

Comment: ITS WORKING NOW, i had to use a unity package i downloaded that imports ironpython and then i had to change some .NET framwork thing and now it works thank you so much for your help!!!! :))))))))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256088/discussion-between-agent-s-and-randomguy660).