# ASP.NET wrong inheritance publishable in .NET 3.5 but not in 4.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I migrated my ASP.NET project from 3.5 to 4.0 (VS2008 to VS2010) and when I tried publishing the site I encountered this error:

> The type 'TYPE' exists in both
>   'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files...\App_Web_1z57x8dg.dll' and
>   'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files...\App_Web_ofaxwney.dll'

However, when I went back to my .NET 3.5/VS2008 project it was publishable without a problem. I found a few SO questions with similar issues, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627190/13064) in particular was very informative. I did the `batch="false"` option but was still encountered the problem.

There had to be an issue with circular reference of sorts. Going back to the .NET 4.0 project I began looking a lot more closely at the errors and found many things like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ViewPresentationTabControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Common_UserControls_PresentationTabControl" %>
```

If you look closely, the `Inherits` tag is pointing to the wrong control. This was a victim of copy and paste code (courtesy of offshore contractor we inherited this project from).

I went through all the errors and fixed the obvious mistake and the project was publishable in .NET 4.0/VS2010.

The purpose of this long drawn out post is why would 3.5 allow that to happen and not 4.0? It seems something like that would cause a major issue in any version, but it obviously didn't.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iisreset
```

and then delete everything from

```
Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

you can in fact clear it for every version of framework installed on your machine v3.0, v3.5, v4.0 etc.

then try republishing the web site. If it doesn't work then, you'll need to go through every code file in the web project and check if namespaces are correct.

If you look at the content of files \Temporary ASP.NET Files\ [projectname] \ *.cs, you'll find out the magic behind the asp.net page code generation engine.

The possible reason in your case is the differnce in build approach: 4.0 for some reason build the whole site content into one big application.dll assembly, so incorrect inherits are surfaced during the build. previously build was happening on a per page basis and one page was compiled into one assembly. To avoid this I normally build .msi packages for web site installation, that enforced the build of full website before packaging and all those errors were surfacing during the build

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I fixed the issue by looking at all locations where the `Inherit` tag was pointing to another file. The question here is why .NET 3.5 allowed it to be published and not 4.0. Was my question not clear enough? Please let me know so I can fix it to avoid any confusion.

Comment: oops. didn't read untill the end :) Differnce in build approach, 4.0 for some reason build the whole site content into one big application.dll assembly, so incorrect inherits are surfaced during the build. previously build was happening on a per page basis and one page was compiled into one assembly. To avoid this I normally build .msi packages for web site installation, that enforced the build of full website before packaging and all those errors were surfacing during the build.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the feed back! You should add that info to your answer so I can accept it as an official answer.

Comment: Updated per your suggestion. Your case is interesting however, are you publishing to the same machine or anohter one?

Comment: It's the the same machine, but I may be using "Publish" loosely here. The way it was done before I started here was "Publish" through VS, and the Precompiled web files were copied over to the IIS server and then had IIS redirect to the new folder (if it wasn't overwritten). I've set up a build machine to basically just publish the site to a folder where the IIS server is located, but we're still copying and/or reassigning as before.