# The type 'basePage' exists in both ASP1.DLL and ASP2.DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks

I have movied my webpage to a new webhost and now I get this exception from time to time :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'basePage' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\60a943dd\2f0f659a\App_Code.n45tvdm2.dll' and
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\60a943dd\2f0f659a\App_Code.4kvzrnma.dll'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 9:  using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; Line 10:  Line 11: public
>   partial class _Default : basePage Line 12: { Line 13:     protected
>   void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Source File:
>   \webstorage\storage_content\28\106228\MySite\public_html\sites\MySite\Default.aspx.cs
>   Line: 11

This has worked well on the old webhost.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596118/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll-pt-2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll) but I do not get this, why have this been working on the old webhost? Nothing have been changed in the ASP.NET solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete every thing from **"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\"** location and try.