# Error: The type exists in both directories

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a MVC2 project I moved a file from App_code to Content folder and compiled it. Then move it back again to App_Code and then changed its Build Action to "Compile". Now I get this error and I don't know how to fix this to make my program work again:

> CS0433: The type 'Helper' exists in
>   both
>   'c:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b00d4b7d\b2553f9c\App_Code.zowyklar.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b00d4b7d\b2553f9c\assembly\dl3\5c6d3537\19f85663_cde9cb01\MyProject.DLL'

Cleaning and Rebuilding doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I had something similar, this time it was a .NET DLL (system.web.something) that was copied inappropriatedly to the project bin dir.  Removing it from the bin directory solved the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net error: "The type 'foo' exists in both "temp1.dll" and "temp2.dll"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll)

Comment: I'm getting this error a lot, but for me clean&rebuild fixes it.  For up to fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try cleaning your solution and then try to rebuild.  Visual Studio probably still has reference to the old dll after it created the new dll.

Comment: try to do a brute force by going to the directory c:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b00d4b7d\b2553f9c\assembly\dl3\5c6d3537\19f85663_cde9cb01\MyProject.DLL and deleting all dlls then clean, rebuild.

Comment: I tried it keeps over and over again. I think I will try to recreate a new project and reimport source thanks for trying :)

Comment: It seems he doesn't like that I change from content to compile for App_Code file.

Comment: @user310291, please don't mark an answer as accepted if it didn't really answer your question.

Comment: I had this issue but cleaning the solution didn't help. Turned out that the offending .dll was still in the `bin` directory despite refence being removed and solution cleaned. I manually deleted the file and it worked.

Comment: @user310291 would you please untick this as the answer? It clearly didn't help you?

Comment: It helped me so it is a possible answer.

Comment: You could also try:

Delete the contents of the temporary folders mentioned (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30139\Temporary ASP.NET Files\xyyy\a155c787\191fc74e\) and (C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\). You can also target the entire Temporary ASP.NET Files directories as opposed to the child one only.
Close Visual Studio.
Delete the contents of the "obj" and "bin" folders within this particular application.
Restart IIS and all of it's associated services.
Open Visual Studio and choose the "Clean Solution" option then "Rebuild Solution" option

Answer (score 40):

This has been answered in a separate question and resolved the problem for me.  Be sure to vote up the original person's answer.

[ASP.Net error: "The type 'foo' exists in both "temp1.dll" and "temp2.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll)

Add the batch="false" attribute to the "compilation" element of the web.config file.

This problem occurs because of the way in which ASP.NET 2.0 uses the application references and the folder structure of the application to compile the application. If the batch property of the element in the web.config file for the application is set to true, ASP.NET 2.0 compiles each folder in the application into a separate assembly.

http://www.sellsbrothers.com/news/showTopic.aspx?ixTopic=1995

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919284

Comment: It may have been answered in a separate question, but this was the one I found ==> more relevant question for me.  I added the batch="false" attribute, but then had to manually delete the files from the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder too (previously doing this hadn't worked, so it seems like I needed both steps).

Comment: The solution by @nullnvoid should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you're building a Web Application, which it appears you are given the MVC2 point, you shouldn't use the App_Code folder. It was not designed to be integrated with Web Application projects.

> When you **Compile** in Visual Studio, all the code in your application
>   (including in **App_Code**) gets compiled into an assembly. When you run
>   your application, asp.net knows about a "special" folder called
>   **App_Code** and compiles the content of it into an assembly with a unique
>   name. Thus, anytime you run the project you'll run into this problem.

The solution:

> Rename your **App_Code** folder to something like "Code" or "Global"
>   (and update your now broken references) & voila, problem solved.

Comment: I put the class outside the App_Code folder , works fine for me, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 13):

My issue was with different version of DevExpress. 
Deleting all contents from **bin** and **obj** folders made my website run again...

Reference:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18674

Comment: This one saved my day. It might not be the entire solution, but surely was part of it :D

Answer (score 11):

Simple Solution worked 100% for me

Put the class outside App_Code Folder

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.in/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

Comment: This is a duplicate of an answer from 2 years earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30169595/2421277

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error :
The type 'MyCustomDerivedFactory' exists in both  and 
My ServiceHost and ServiceHostFactory derived classes where in the App_Code folder of my WCF service project. Adding

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation batch="false" />
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```

didn't solve the error but moving my ServiceHost and ServiceHostFactory derived classes in a separate Class library project did it.

Answer (score 5):

**TRY THIS ONE!**

Normally, when this happen locally, i clean all the aspnet temp folder. But recently it was happing when i published my website in Azure. So "clean temp aspnet folder" was not a solution.

After searching on the internet, i founded this:

[Clear Temp ASP.NET files from Azure Web Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408271/clear-temp-asp-net-files-from-azure-web-site)

It works for me!

Answer (score 3):

The App_Code folder isn't intended to be used with MVC Projects (WAP).

Files in the App_Code folder gets compiled automatically as part of a special dll. If the Build Action property on the file is set to Compile, the same class will also get compiled as part of the main dll and you will end up with two copies.

Setting the Build Action property to None makes sure there is only one copy of the class in the project. The compiler will not catch any errors in the App_Code folder when building but Intellisense will still validate the code but compile-time errors won't show up until it is compiled on-the-fly.

The recommended solution is to put code in a normal folder and make sure the Build Action is set to Compile.

Comment: This is a duplicate an existing answer from two years before. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30169595/2421277

Answer (score 1):

There might be two classes with same name "Helper" in your solution/project. Change name of one of them and then rebuild

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I just faced the same issue and resolved it in this way. This was solution to my problem and it might be helpful for anyone facing same issue. There shouldn't be any restriction to comment without sufficient reputation. You may learn from experience of new people as well

Comment: I know, I thought the same thing when I started here. If you feel like posting a request for this you can do this on "Meta Stackoverflow". Would be interested on what results from this request

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in one of my projects. Turns out the problem started from me coping a Master page.

The problem will also occur if two pages "Inherit" the same page.

I had the following line of code at the top of my "LoginMaster.Master" & "MasterPage.Master"

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MainMaster.master.cs" Inherits="Master_Pages_Header" %>
```

I changed the Inherits on my "LoginMaster.Master to:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LoginMaster.master.cs" Inherits="Master_Pages_LoginMaster" %>
```

I was immediately able to publish my project with out any problems. Hopefully this works for someone else. I apologize for not use the correct terms.

You will also need to change the class in the .cs to match the Inherits name. If you don't it will cause an error.

IE:

```
public partial class Master_Pages_LoginMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are migrating ASP.NET 2.0 Website to .NET Web APP 4.5, you can have that issue too. And puting batch=false, adding a namespace etc... can not work.

The workaround is to rename the old App_Code folder (or any problematic folder) to Old_App_Code (like the automatic process do it), or any other name.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, In my case, I noticed, that cleaning a solution doesn't clear the bin folder in the visual studio. There was old compiled .dll present in the folder that is causing the issue.

Solutions:

1. Manually delete bin folder and recompile.
2. In case of publishing, select delete existing files prior to publish.

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Same here. I delete the bin folder, rebuilt, done! Thank tou mohammad

Answer (score 0):

In the Web Application(not Web Site),  I change App_Code*.cs Build Action(file properties) from **Compile** to **Content**. then the problem solve.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the real cause of the problem in this case.

Comment: The problem with this solution is you are telling Visual Studio to not compile this file.  While it will make the error go away you are treating the symptom not the cause.  On top of it you are no longer checking this file for compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to items with same name but different extensions in my project. One was accountRep.aspx and the other accountRep.rpt made by Crystal Report. Problem solved when I changed accountRep.rpt to accountReport.rpt

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution which worked for me was to change all references from

```
CodeFile="~/..."
```

to

```
CodeBehind="~/..."
```

in all .master and .aspx pages

This occurred when converting an old website to a proper web application with a solution file.

I didn't find this information anywhere else so hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by checking `Delete all existing files prior to publish` in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error when I had mistakenly named a class the same as the class it was inheriting from.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pretty much every suggestion on this page, but had to delete visual studio 2017 completely off my machine. I reinstalled the latest version (2019) and it magically worked. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing one of the unneeded NuGet packaged referenced in the dll files causing this conflict.

So in this case I had both ZXing.Net and ZXing.Net.Mobile installed. Since I was creating a mobile app in Xamarin Forms, removing the ZXing.Net NuGet package resolved this.

Be sure to check and make sure you don't have redundant NuGet packages for different frameworks, i.e. ASP.Net versus Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change folder name

- from `APP_CODE`
- to `CODE`.

This fixed my issue.

Alternatively you can move to another folder all your code files.

Answer (score 0):

Comment one of the crystal report version part in Webconfig in assemblies
and build.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).