# Getting Error CS0433

Tags: asp.net

> error CS0433: The type 'ucTerms' exists in both 'c:\Users\satyajit.singh\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\eoc\f63b2378\43228109\App_Web_cez09cff.dll' and 'c:\Users\satyajit.singh\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\eoc\f63b2378\43228109\App_Web_frn_iozf.dll'

I can see that theere is a User Control "ucTerms" which is contained in the "User Control" folder under also under the root (main solution) . I researched a lot and tried different solutions like setting the "batch = false", deleting the temporary folder but none have worked.

The web site builds successfully but this error pops up when I try to publish the website.

can anyone help me on this. I have been working on this error for last 3 days.

Thanks in advance,
Satyam

Comment: What is cause this error 3 days ago ? I mean how this error starts ? what you change ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried these?

[Error: The type exists in both directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425638/asp-net-error-the-type-exists-in-both-directories),

http://www.pgs-soft.com/the-type-x-exists-in-both-y1-dll-and-y2-dll.html,

http://forums.asp.net/t/980517.aspx

if none of these help, try to isolate the issue:
remove your user control from the project (make sure you save it somehwere else) to see if its only this one user control that has the issue, or every other one as well, this information may be helpful