# Clear Temp ASP.NET files from Azure Web Site

Tags: asp.net, file, azure, temp

I have a issue with a ASP.NET nopCommerece Plugin that seems to be cached on the server.

I have cleared the nopCommerce cache and restated the application but it didn't help

One of the normal steps is to clear out \Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files but since this is a Azure Web Site, I only have access via FTP and I don't have access to that directory.

How do I go about clearing the Temp Files.

Answer (score 13):

when you publish the website on to azure, by right clicking and choosing publish, there should be a option under setting saying: Remove additional files at destination. Check it and publish.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do to fix a `System.Web.HttpCompileException` problem I was having.

Comment: If you are using continuous integration or deployment from Visual Studio Online rather than deploying directly from Visual Studio, I've had luck editing a couple of settings in the build definition to make this happen. While editing the build definition, go to Deployment in the Process section and set both "Allow Upgrade" and "Do Not Delete" to false, then save the build definition and queue a new build.

Comment: Thanks!  "Remove additional files at destination" worked 100%.

Comment: This solved the issue I had where I renamed a partial view but Azure was still holding onto the old file and throwing a "An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request" error.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this by creating a temporary file in the bin folder of my website.

This casuses the temporary hash file to change in the temp folder and then ASP.Net rebuilds everything.

See [here](http://shazwazza.com/post/Taming-the-BuildManager-ASPNet-Temp-files-and-AppDomain-restarts.aspx) for more details about the hash file and its relation to rebuilding.

Remove Additional files didn't fix my problem as it only removes files in webroot not the temporary asp.net files. As far as I can see with Azure you have no access directly to the temporary asp.net files