# Using a wcf client class file in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am returning a class file in a WCF application. The class file AuthenticationService.cs generated from svcutil.exe of wsdl (WCF app) is being saved in the App_Code and using in my project.

```
public ActionResult ViewName()
    {
  AuthenicationServiceClient client = new AuthenicationServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenicationService");
  IList<CategoryInfo> category = new List<CategoryInfo>();
  category = client.GetCategories(0, true);
  return View(category);
}
```

the class CategoryInfo is present in AuthenticationService.cs which i can access from controller but not able to use the same in the View. When i use the same CategoryInfo in View it is showing error message

```
In View
@model CategoryInfo
```

class CategoryInfo

> *Error:
>   The type 'CategoryInfo exists in both 'D:\ProjectName\Project Path\bin\ProjectName.dll' and
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30309\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\1664c01d_shadow\b956618\414288438\30335072\App_Code.j4b-_1mm.dll*

is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET error: The type exists in both directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425638/asp-net-error-the-type-exists-in-both-directories)

Comment: i havent placed any of dll's in the directory. Its autogenerated @CodeCaster

Comment: It's a question that I think closely resembles yours. Click the link, verify the problem, check that none of the answers apply and _then_ you can tell me I linked to the wrong one. For now, it seems like you can try a few answers in there to solve your problem. I do think though @Darin has a point regarding the App_Code directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reply to my own question.**

I was using the same CategoryInfo using the web service as well as in the project file as reference. My issue is resolved by removing the naming conflict by removing the referrence and fetching the CategoryInfo only from the Webservice client file.

Now i am not getting the error any more.

Answer (score 3):

> The class file AuthenticationService.cs generated from svcutil.exe of
>   wsdl (WCF app) is being saved in the App_Code

That's the problem. The `App_Code` folder should not be used by a Web Application Project type (which is what ASP.NET MVC uses). It is meant for WebSites. So move those classes somewhere else and DELETE the `App_Code` folder which should not be present in a precompiled web application. Please read here about the differences between a Web Application Project type and a Web Site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

The reason why your code doesn't work is because when you precompile the project (as it is a web application type), the `CategoryInfo` class goes into the resulting assembly. Except that ASP.NET for everything that's inside the `App_Code` folder, at runtime generates dynamic assemblies and places them in the output. So basically you end up with 2 assemblies containing the same class.

Comment: placed the  in Model and tried, then with controller. Getting the same error

Comment: Clean the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30309\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1664c01d_shadow\b956618\414288438\30335072` folder where might have left some assemblies from the previous runs.

Comment: yeah done with it. Fixed the issue, but in future will the file be generated again at any point of time and create the same trouble?

Comment: I don't know. Personally I never use the Visual Studio's built-in Wizards for generating service reference. I use the `svcutil.exe` utility directly and then take the .cs file into my project. This way I have full control of everything.

Comment: the worry i have mentioned in the previous comment has started. I am getting the same message again now. So every time i need to check on deleting the files looking at the particular path manually. I wish if i had some solution where this file was not generated twice.