# I get an error in my MVC project (system.ıo.compression.CompressioLevel)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.io.file, system.io.compression

MVC project adding  Roxy Manager plugin (CKEditor Plugin)

I get an error on the C # side.

[image]
How can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio is not able to differentiate between the 2 dll references.   Have a look at your references as may need to tidy them up and maybe try cleaning the solution and rebuilding it but also look at similar issue on stack overflow such as [Error: The type exists in both directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425638/asp-net-error-the-type-exists-in-both-directories) or similar