# User temp AppData error while publishing project in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, temp

I imported an UserControl into my page:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Forms/Admin/UserControls/wucAutoCompleteCity.ascx" TagName="wucAutoCompleteCity" TagPrefix="uc12" %>
```

and I am using it like this

```
            <li>
               <uc12:wucAutoCompleteCity id="wucAutoCompleteCity1" runat="server" visible="true" />
            </li>
```

But when I try to publish the solution, Visual Studio 2012 is throwing this error

> Type 'Cienworks.View.wucAutoCompleteCity ' exists in both
>   'c:\Users\Lucasp\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\mysolution\cc396d72\280f05fc\App_Web_wucautocompletecity.ascx.33f5864.dll'
>   and 'c:\Users\Lucasp\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\mysolution\cc396d72\280f05fc\App_Web_imw4lcx2.dll'

I have no ideia what is causing it. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll

Comment: I tried all those answers, but I still having this problem