# Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Helpers.Json' exists in both

Tags: asp.net

I just checked out a .NET project to work on. However, when I run it, it gives me this compile error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Helpers.Json' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2c3c3525\f643d2c6\assembly\dl3\a363418d\c830c6f0_9d86d001\System.Web.Helpers.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll'
>
> Line 57:             db.SubmitChanges();
>   Line 58: 
>   Line 59:             Context.Response.Write(Json.Encode(new { success = true }));
>   Line 60: 
>   Line 61:         }

I tried to look for solution online but it didn't help. The steps I followed:

Manually deleting everything all the content inside the TEMP file
adding batch="false" in compilation tag in the webconfig file

None of them helped... Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can you please go to your web.config and find this "System.Web.Helpers" and share with us that section of your web.config?

Comment: There is no System.Web.Helpers section in my WebConfig file: There is only System.Web and tags like protocols, pages, authentication etc.. But there is no System.Web.Helpers

Comment: The only thing about System helpers in webconfig file is this   <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and adding `batch="false"` in the `<compilation />` tag of the `web.config` solved the problem.

Solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371426/asp-net-error-the-type-foo-exists-in-both-temp1-dll-and-temp2-dll)

Comment: this didn't work for me. I am migrating an old asp.net web site (asp.net 1 or 2?) to .net 4.5. 

I needed to move delegate event handler declarations to separate files.